# How to save the output of a command only after 15s in a file?

Tags: bash, shell

I wanted to save the output of the command 'airodump-ng wlan0' in a file, but just after about 15 secounds that the command started. I found something like this:

```
{ airodump-ng wlan0  sleep 15 ; } 2> log.txt
```

but I get an error
"airodump-ng --help" for help.

Comment: You are missing the semicolon to separate the `airodump-ng` command from the `sleep` command. `{ airodump-ng wlan0; sleep 15; } 2> log.txt`

Comment: Maybe you could clarify if you wamt to record the first 15 seconds and discard the rest, or if you want to discard the first 15 seconds and record the rest, please?

Comment: Kark Setchell, 2 options would be great, save the firts 15 secounds, or just take a snapshot at the 15 secounds. Sorry not to be clear

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with `airodump` and its output, but you could try something like this which reads its output and discards it until 15s have elapsed:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Work out time to start output, 15s from now
((tplus15=SECONDS+15))

airodump-ng wlan0 | while read line ; do
   [ $SECONDS -gt $tplus15 ] && echo "$line"
done
```

If you want the output in a file, add `> someFile.txt` after the last `done`.

If `airodump` outputs on its `stderr`, you may need to add `2>&1` after `airodump-ng wlan0`, like this:

```
airodump-ng wlan0 2>&1 | while read ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to start the dump, then wait 15 seconds, then kill the dump. Just putting the sleep command after the dump command will not start the sleep until after the airodump has finished, which is not what OP wants. Note also stderr is from OP's original idea.

```
#!/bin/sh

airodump-ng wlan0 2> log.txt &
sleep 15
kill %1
```

<s>To me, this is a simpler solution than @Mark Setchell's</s> This takes the first 15 seconds of output, rather than the output after 15 seconds as @MarkSetchell's answer does.

Comment: I believe your command saves the first 15s of output then exits. Mine discards the first 15s then saves whatever ensues.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, I get the first 15 seconds. That's the way I read the OP request, but on re-reading I see the ambiguity.

Answer (score -3):

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 15
airodump-ng wlan0 > test.txt
```

Is it working please have a look

Comment: This will pause for 15 seconds *before* executing the command (not after).